# 404 For me only

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I am trying to install the forums software - Xenforo.

I uploaded every single file. However, it comes back a Cpanel default page (Future home of something quite cool).

And when I want to visit xxx.php page, it comes a 404 error.

I tried to clear the cache and cookies on Microsoft Edge and Chrome. Even a clean Firefox is still not working.

When I contacted Godaddy Support, they said that at their end my site is working. My PC and phone are not working as well even they are in different network provider.

I can just come here for HELP!!!! Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 0):

You should try clearing your cache or using an incognito browser.

There are great people over on the Xenforo Community Forums that can help you out with the installation.

Xenforo Community Forums: https://xenforo.com/community/forums/installation-upgrade-and-import-support.23/